# Java - Reusing Timer Object after calling cancel

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have an application in Java where I need to schedule a `TimerTask`which will be executed after 500ms , however if a certain event occurs, I must reset the timer for this task (so that we must wait another 500ms for it to execute). I have a `timer` declared for the whole class.  I use the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (curr_pck == my_pck) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myTask();
                    }
                }, 500);
            }

}  


public static void myTask() {

    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();

    timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myTask();
        }
    }, 500);

  //EXECUTE CODE WHICH ISN'T RELEVANT TO THE QUESTION

}
```

I know that if I use `timer.cancel()` I can't reuse the timer object, however I thought reinitialising it in the line `timer = new Timer()` should solve this issue. Is there any way around this?

EXCEPTION on line `timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {` inside `myTask()` function:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.`

Comment: You should write a [MCVE] for this and show the exact and full error.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Knowing the scope of the variables is necessary to answer your question. Please post more code and the stack trace.

Comment: Please let me know if the edit helps

Comment: Edit is still not self-contained, nobody can actually try this and reproduce your error. Try to get it to a point where it can be run by others and shows the behaviour you are having a problem with.

Comment: Perhaps you should save a reference to the actual timer task. You can safely cancel the *task* without invalidating the timer. Still, the situation you present seems to indicate some kind of race condition, and you should still create a [mcve] if you want to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Create a class Timerr with the appropriate methods. Then access it as if it were a normal timer.

```
public class Timerr
{
    private Timer timer;

    public Timerr()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        start();
    }
}
```

Create instance

```
private Timerr timer = new Timerr();
```

Do your reset

```
if(condition)
{
    timerr.reset();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You may want to check out Java's Swing timer.  It works somewhat differently and you may have to write an internal class or an actionlistener, but the Swing timer includes .stop() and .restart(), which seem like they would work better in your application.

Comment: Swing's timer runs its task on the EDT. So it is really only proper for Swing applications.

Comment: Unless we know that this is a Swing application, then this answer is incorrect.